# Inserting an enum into Database using ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I have a model named User which has properties like Username, Password, Email Address, and SystemRole, which is a foreign key from the table "SystemRole" (with two properties: Id and SystemRoleTypes (type enum)). This is my SystemRole model:

```
[Table("SystemRole")]
    public class SystemRole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public SystemRoleTypes SystemRoleType { get; set; }
    }
    public enum SystemRoleTypes
    {
        User = 3,
        Manager = 2,
        Admin = 1
    }
```

I wanted to populate the User table from the database to have a sample user to be shown on the list, but first the SystemRole table should be populated through EF. How can I get EF to use the enum for populating the table?

And this is my User model:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PassWord { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public SystemRole SystemRole { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What result do you get now? I think this should work as you describe

Comment: By default it will write the enum values (int); do yo want to store the names instead?

Comment: The problem is that when I want to populate the User table, I can't add value to SystemRole column, because the SystemRole table is not populated, therefore I can't determine which role this user is gonna have.

Comment: Have you done `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`?

Comment: If you go to the `SystemRole` SQL table and watch the `Designer` you will figure out that the data type of `enum` map to `int` in the database. you wanna Insert Some `SystemRole` to database ?! Or you have problem with adding `User` because there is no `SystemRole` ??? your problem is not clear !!

Comment: Of course I used the package manager console commands.

Comment: There's no data in SystemRole table in database. Yes, I have problem with adding a new user, because there's no SystemRole type to be selected for the new user. The actual question was how to populate the SystemRole table through the enum, so that the user could be added to the table.